# How to generate all cyrillic font files for Computer Modern at once?

Tags: fonts

I use UTF8 and `inputenc.sty` and for latin characters it just works.

Recently I typed a little Russian in cyrillic into my source file. The document would not compile due to missing font file. I had to compile it as `root` once so the fonts could be generated for all user. Nevertheless I have to repeat this anytime I use a new font size or shape.

Is there a way to generate it all at once, at least for cyrillic in Computer Modern font?

Comment: Can you show us an example of a simple document that had to be compiled as root to work?